# Nginx updating Ingress status for ignored ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller, ingress-nginx

I have updated the  to version nginx/1.19.10, with the new update, the nginx monitors all the ingress even the one managed by AWS, whenever the nginx starts, I get the error:

```
I0710 11:23:55.798939       7 store.go:426] "Ignoring ingress because of error while validating ingress class" ingress="system/Monitor" error="ingress class annotation is not equal to the expected by Ingress Controller"
```

this is expected as the Monitor ingress is managed by AWS, but after recreating the Monitor ingress, I can see it gets created succesfully with the desired hostname from AWS, BUT after couple of seconds the nginx update the status:

```
I0700 12:31:49.768027       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"system", Name:"Monitor", UID:"xxxxxx", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"1111111", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0700 12:31:52.719320       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"system", Name:"Monitor", UID:"xxxxxx", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"1111111", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0700 12:32:44.483534       7 status.go:299] "updating Ingress status" namespace="system" ingress="monitor-alb" currentValue=[{IP: Hostname:monitor-alb-111223344.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com Ports:[]}] newValue=[{IP:34.223.100.122 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
I0700 12:32:44.491418       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"system", Name:"Monitor", UID:"xxxxxx", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"1111111", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
```

I am not sure which config responsible for that, even i tested by removing the parameter "watch-ingress-without-class=true" but that didnt help.

Any suggestions please?

I tried to removed watch-ingress-without-class=true, but that didnt help.